# PHP Include slideshow—not lining up, simple css answer I'm sure

Tags: php, css, include, slideshow

I have simple slideshow on my home page as a php include. It shows up, but it seems to be floating up to the top of the page, and not falling in line with all of the other includes, ie, header, menu, etc. In addition, the image isn't lined up with the arrows. Here is where it lives:

http://www.starhilldesignstudio.com/adventure-suites/index-test.php

And here is the slideshow solo (arrows line up):

http://www.starhilldesignstudio.com/adventure-suites/slideshow-home.php

My html code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
</div>
<div id="mainContent" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
<div class="center margin-top "><?php include 'slideshow-home.php'; ?></div>
<?php include 'home-blurb.php'; ?>
<?php include 'home-list.php'; ?>
<?php include 'bottom-stripe.php'; ?>
<div id="footer2">
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Looks good to me. Make sure your `display: inline` / `display: inline-block` elements have no extra whitespace.

Comment: It works on chrome but not on firefox. It would help if you would stop working on it for a second. There are a ton of inherent issues with your coding, I'm noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a misplaced include, place your include function where you wanted to put your file to.

Example you wanted to put it before your content in between your header and footer:

```
include "header.php"
include "slider.php"
include "content.php"
include "footer.php"
```

Let us know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
</div>
<div id="mainContent" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
<!-- Add this... -->
<div style="clear:both;padding-bottom:10px"></div>

<!--<div class="clear"></div>consider making the above style into a class.-->

<div class="center margin-top "><?php include 'slideshow-home.php'; ?></div>
<?php include 'home-blurb.php'; ?>
<?php include 'home-list.php'; ?>
<?php include 'bottom-stripe.php'; ?>
<div id="footer2">
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```